# Service method call with Thymeleaf onclick

Tags: java, spring-boot, service, thymeleaf

I'm trying to call a method of a spring boot service from thymeleaf, each time the user clicks on a button. With my code, my method is called when the page loads but not when the button is clicked. Here is the th:onclick in my button tag.

```
th:onclick="${@myService.myFunction()}"
```

Is it not possible to do that or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it th:onclick calls your function when the page is loading because it is processing the template and is calculating the value of the attribute "onclick". The String your method returns will be the value of onclick. Thymeleaf cannot call beans methods directly from the button. You have to call javascript functions, not bean methods. Thymeleaf can only call bean methods during template processing. You'll have to POST to some URL to cal your method.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to call service with the help of thyme leaf,you can call api from thyme leaf page and call that method.

```html
<input type="submit"  onclick="save()"/>
```

On save method call one api.